# How to make NSString macro?

Tags: objective-c, macros, xcode4, nsstring

How to make a macro that represents a constant NSString value? I'm getting 
"Multi-character character constant" and "Character constant too long for its type" warnings when defining in Xcode 4:

```
#define LEVELTYPEGLASS @"Glass"
```

Do I need to escape something?

Comment: It's correct. How exactly are you using it?

Comment: check your spelling, if there is `@` char and if you use double double quotation marks. Probably it can by typo, or tell us where do you place this code

Comment: I have a separate file for macros placed in Supporting Files group. This header file is imported in <My_project>-Prefix.pch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid using defines for string constants. Define as an extern in the header file like this:

```
extern NSString * const MYLevelTypeGlass;
```

And them implement in any implementation file:

```
NSString * const MYLevelTypeGlass = @"Glass";
```

This gives a few more characters to type, but adds allot of benefits like better typing for Xcode, guaranteed object identity (no duplicate strings). This is how Apple do it, if its good enough for them, it should be good for you.

Comment: Hm, the solution brakes my working conventions a little bit :( Currently, all my macros reside in one macro header file that is automatically included in all my custom classes.

Comment: Would you mind explaining why we should avoid just using a define to do this?  Not questioning, just curious.

Comment: The very reasons I mentioned; Xcode and the compiler get better types handling (for refactoring for example), and equality. You can do `foo == MYLevelTypeGlass` in your code and it is safe.

Comment: @Centurion - Nothing stops you from having all the defined `NSString` constants in a single header file that is automatically included. You can use the same file, with the same names if you like.

Comment: Yes but you suggested to put actual constant value in any implementation file (NSString * const MYLevelTypeGlass = @"Glass";
). IMHO, in that case, the value of @"Glass" moves from my macros file to somewhere else. Please be so kind to clarify I think I'm missing smth :) I just need to store all the constant values (macros) in one header file.

Comment: @Centurion - Yes you must have some implementation file to put the actual implementation of the extern constant in, a Constants.h/Constants.m pair works perfectly fine. Just as with a function implementation there must be only one implementation, therefor it can not be in the header file that will be *realised*.

Comment: Thanks but I'm still unable to get this working :( I have created an empty Constants.h/Constants.m pair, moved all my macros to header file and also placed "extern NSString * const LEVELTYPEGLASS;" there. Then added "NSString * const MYLevelTypeGlass = @"Glass";" line to Constants.m. But then I'm getting error "expected identifier or '(' before 'G' ". And I'm getting a little bit different error "expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
 " when including Constants.h in the <My_project>-Prefix.pch file

Comment: Sorry for maybe silly questions. Just starting to program in objective-c. Could you be so kind to show example of Constants.h/Constants.m. Are you using some method in implementation file for setting those extern constants?

Comment: @Centurion - If you name it `LEVELTYPEGLASS` in the header file, then you must name it the same in the implementation file. I used `MYLevelTypeGlass` as an alternate example since it is a name that follows the Cocoa naming conventions.

Comment: Sorry for my stupid typo. Just fixed but one of errors remains "expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or 'attribute' before '*' token " when including Constants.h in the <My_project>-Prefix.pch file". The definition is OK itself but I believe the problem is with #import "Constants.h" line when adding to <My_project>-Prefix.pch. How do you include those files for whole project?

Comment: @Centurion let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2036/discussion-between-peylow-and-centurion)

Answer (score 1):

The solution suggested by PeyloW is great. But I just want to note that I got the solution working after I have added #import "Foundation/Foundation.h" to header file. So the header file Constants.h should look like:

```
#import "Foundation/Foundation.h"

extern NSString * const LEVELTYPEGLASS; 
#define IMAGECOUNT 5
...
```

Then, implementation file looks like:

```
#import "Constants.h"

NSString * const LEVELTYPEGLASS = @"Glass";
```

And if you need to include that into whole project you need to import that in -Prefix.pch file:

```
#import "Constants.h"
```

In that case, all the macro definitions resides in Constants.h header file, and some NSString constants resides in Constants.m implementation file. Again, thanks to PeyloW :)